# Google Cloud Functions, how do you specify Firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 1 GCP project and 2 Firebase projects (dev and prod).

For my Cloud Function (CF) to connect to a Firebase (FB) project, I use the following approach inside the CF:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

This automatically connects to the default (prod) Firebase and works well.

After I added the second FB project (dev), I want dev CFs to connect to dev FB and others to connect to production FB project.

I suppose I can select that from the `config().firebase` but do you know how?

Best

Comment: Just to add, I know I could achieve this by using the 2 different serviceAccount.json files and pick either one. I want to avoid putting these inside the CFs for security measures since they contain private keys.

Comment: To connect to your Firebase project, do you include the .json generated key into your Cloud Function? If so, How do you do it? I am familiar with Cloud Functions and could find a way to achieve what you want.